# chess game in prolog

Tags: prolog

For one of my courses in the University i need a chess game implemented in prolog.
My homework assignment it to build/improve the AI of the game.

I don't want to write the entire game from scratch,I was wondering if there is a source code for a game in prolog or perhaps another language C,C++,C#,Java that exposes a API to a prolog program.

Thanks,
Koby Meir

Comment: Does your assignment *expect* you to write the entire game from scratch?

Comment: It would be easier, I'm afraid, to get a pony. I think you must have misunderstood the assignment, it's very hard to believe that your teacher expects you to go out and find an existing AI and improve it as opposed to handing you one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is:
% Chess -- Mar. 1, 1987     Mike Carlton

You find it in the benchmarks of:
http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~bart.demoen/hProlog/

Can't tell you more, since I didn't try it.

Bye

Comment: I'll try it! Thanks for the link, not easy to spot.

Comment: Here's a direct link to the bookmarks (`tar.gz`) mentioned in the answer: http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/Bart.Demoen/hProlog/iclpgcbenches.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Gnu [Chess](http://www.gnu.org/s/chess/) it's in C, could be integrated using foreign language interface. It's not going to be an easy task, though.

SWI-Prolog has a Chess Board sample partially implemented in XPCE, its GUI framework, but no game engine.

Answer (score -1):

My answer may be late respective to your assignement deadline :

See [Prolog Chess](http://www.fraber.de/games/chess/) chess engine (source code distibution), initialy implemented in Turbo Prolog. Other Prolog ports also available.

Comment: @mwnjaraz: Thanks anyway, maybe someone else will find it useful